# Independence of Multivariate Normal Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, independence

$\mathbf {Problem:}$ Let $X \sim N_n(μ, Σ)$. For column vectors $a$ and $b$ of length $n$, show that
$a^T X$ and $b^T X$ are independent **if and only if**

$a^T Σb = 0$. Where $N_n(μ, Σ)$ denote $n$ dimensional multivariate normal distribution.

$\mathbf {My Attempt:}$ We know $a^TX ∼ N_n(a^Tμ, a^TΣa)$ and $b^TX \sim N_n(b^Tμ, b^TΣb)$. To show independence, I need to show that, the joint density of $Y=a^TX$ and $Z=b^TX$ is,

$$ f_{Y,Z}(y,z) = f_{Y}(y) \cdot f_Z(z).$$

But how to prove the above claim? Also I don't have any idea in which step, I have to use $a^T Σb = 0$. What about the converse? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It might be easier to use the moment generating function of multinormal distribution.

Comment: Can you give me the outline of the solution using moment generating function?

Comment: I gave you one. Let me know if it is helpful.

Comment: @Shashi : I'm presuming that where you wrote "multinomial" it was a typo and you meant "multivariate normal".

Comment: $$
\operatorname{cov}(a^T X, b^T X) = a^T\Big( \operatorname{cov}(X,X) \Big) b = a^T \Sigma b.
$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy exactly! I forgot the name lol

Comment: @MichaelHardy can you give a proof of the co-variance formula ,you have written ? I am just a beginner in this course , your explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: @RATNODEEPBAIN : Let $\mu=\operatorname EX\in\mathbb R^p$ and $\nu=\operatorname E Y\in\mathbb R^q.$ Then $$ \operatorname{cov}(X,Y) = \operatorname E((X-\mu)(Y-\nu))^T \in \mathbb R^{p\times q}. $$ For constant, i.e. non-random, matrices $A\in\mathbb R^{k\times p},$ $B\in\mathbb R^{\ell\times q},$ we have $\Big(B(Y-\nu)\Big)^T = (Y-\nu)^T B^T$ (where the order of multiplication has been inverted), so $$ \operatorname{cov}\big( AX, BY\big) = \operatorname E( A(X-\mu) (Y-\nu)^T B^T).$$ Then you need to show that that is $A\Big( \operatorname E( (X-\mu) (Y-\nu)^T) \Big) B^T.$

Comment: Therefore $$ \operatorname{cov}\big( AX, BY\big) = A\Big( \operatorname{cov} (X,Y) \Big) B^T \in \mathbb R^{k\times\ell}. $$ @RATNODEEPBAIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}$ **An outline using MGF.**

Notice that $$M_X(v):=\E[\exp(v^TX)]=\exp\left(v^T\mu+\frac 1 2 v^T\Sigma v \right)$$ Moreover for $t\in\mathbb R$:
$$M_{X}(t(a+b))=\exp\left(t(a+b)^T\mu+\frac 1 2 t^2(a+b)^T\Sigma (a+b) \right)$$
On the other hand:
$$M_X(t(a+b)) =\E[\exp(t(a+b)^TX)] = \E[\exp(t(a^TX+b^TX))]=M_{a^TX+b^TX}(t) $$
A theorem about MGF says two random variables are independent iff the MGF of the sum is the product of the MGF. So you can question yourself when do we have:
$$M_{a^TX+b^TX}(t)\stackrel{?}{=}M_{a^TX}(t)M_{b^TX}(t)$$
After doing that, you will get an iff statement about the independence of $a^TX$ and $b^TX$.